# Why the second js file included in header is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in a JQuery Mobile App and Phonegap.
I declare a File1.js file in the header, as the last file in the header.

So, I have a little function within the js file:

```
$('#SendMailButton').bind('tap',function(e){
    alert("Hello");
});
```

When the user press the button, everything works ok.

Latter, I move this function from the File1.js file to a new File2.js file
and I declare File2.js below the File1.js as following:

```
<script src="js/File1.js"></script>
<script src="js/File2.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't works.

The complete header is as:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="js/File1.js"></script>
<script src="js/File2.js"></script>
```

What am I wrong?

Comment: Is that part of code within a `$(function() { ... code here ... })` or `$(document).ready(function() { ... code here ... })` ? Was it whithin File1?

Comment: Did you check any errors exist in File1.js, like mismatching brackets etc., since you moved the function? Two things you may check: File2.js loading properly in the page you are working & what happens if you move include of File2.js before File1.js

Comment: Yes, the code was inside the deviceready listener. So, I changed the this:

    $('#SendMailButton').bind('tap',function(e){

for this:

    $(document).bind('tap','#SendMailButton',function(){

and now it works!

Thank you @PetervanderWal, you have inspired me!

Comment: How could I increase a vote for your correct answer?

Comment: Ok, I think I have not enough reputation to mark an answer as correct, still! Thank you at all

Answer (score 0):

You are loading two jquery.mobile, also you are loading jquery after load jquery mobile, try with this head:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="js/File1.js"></script>
<script src="js/File2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Héctor, I changed the header as you suggested and everything works Ok.